# Is there a complete list of possible pipeline statuses in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on a tool to visualize GitLab pipelines and part of that is to take the status of the pipeline into account to color the entry accordingly. I know of the following statuses

- success
- failed
- pending (when no worker is available yet)
- manual (when a manual stop condition exists)

Does someone know where I can get a complete list of all possible statuses? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 4):

Can be found under description for "status" attribute: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html :

> The status of pipelines, one of: created, waiting_for_resource, preparing, pending, running, success, failed, canceled, skipped, manual, scheduled

Comment: Thank you very much, I have absolutely no idea how I missed that…

Comment: Which of the states are "Final" states? A bit weird that it is not documented. For success and failed is clear, but what about manual?